# How to enable HTML5 mode in Express without breaking NodeMailer?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, nodemailer

everyone.  I'm making my first Node + Express + Angular app.

I kinda used https://github.com/codeschool/StayingSharpWithAngularSTB as a boiler plate.

The general layout is

[folder] app
--------- [Sub-Folder] Assets (Javascript, css, images etc.)
--------- [Sub-Folder] Pages (This contains ng-view stuff)
--------- [Sub-Folder] Views 
-------------------- index.html (This is the main index.html that holds everything together)

[folder] node_modules
   [folder] server
--------- [Sub-Folder] Controllers
---------------------- core.server.controller.js 
--------- expressConfig.js 
--------- routes.js 
   app.js 
   package.json

So here's the my server configuring files: 
 app.js

```
var app = require("./server/routes");

// Start the server
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
  app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

/server/expressConfig.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function(app, express) {
  // Serve static assets from the app folder. This enables things like javascript
  // and stylesheets to be loaded as expected. You would normally use something like
  // nginx for this, but this makes for a simpler demo app to just let express do it.
  app.use("/", express.static("app/"));

  // Set the view directory, this enables us to use the .render method inside routes
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/../app/views');

  // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  // parse application/json
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
};
```

/server/routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var core = require('./controllers/core.server.controller')
// Load Express Configuration
require('./expressConfig')(app, express);

// Root route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html', {root: app.settings.views});
});


// routes for sending forms
app.route('/contact-form').post(core.sendMail);
app.route('/table-form').post(core.sendTableRes);
app.route('/artist-form').post(core.sendArtistRes);
module.exports = app;
```

/server/controllers/core.server.controller.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: //my gmail,
        pass: //my gmail password
    }
});
// Send an email when the volunteer form is submitted
exports.sendMail = function (req, res){
    var data = req.body;
    transporter.sendMail({
        from: //my gmail,
        to: //another gmail,
        subject: data.volunteerName+ ' wants to volunteer for our event 2016',
        text: 'Volunteer Info \n Name : '+data.volunteerName+'\n Phone Number : '
+data.volunteerNum+'\n E-mail : ' +data.volunteerEmail
    });
    res.json(data);
};
// Other similar mailing functions
```

And here's one of the angular controllers that sends the mail 
volunteerFormController.js

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('FormController', function($http){
    this.volunteer = {
    };
    this.addVolunteer = function(){
        var data = ({
            volunteerName : this.volunteer.name,
            volunteerEmail : this.volunteer.email,
            volunteerNum : this.volunteer.phone
        });

    $http.post('/contact-form', data).
     then(function(response) {
//show thank you message with animate.css classes and hide form
        $(".thanksFriend").addClass("animated tada showBlock");
        $("form").addClass("flipOutX animated hideBlock");
      }, function(response) {
            $(".sorryFriend").addClass("animated tada showBlock");
      });

    };
});
```

And this works just fine! But if I enable html5 mode in Angular and serve up the index in Express using

```
app.use(function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html', {root: app.settings.views});
});
```

in the routes.js file, Html 5 mode works great! No 404s when I remove the pound and refresh but then the none of my contact forms work, and the console isn't giving me any errors... My server files are pretty small and it's not super complicated so it should be pretty easy to figure out how to have both HTML5 mode AND working contact forms.  Any ideas? I don't know much about Express and I used a tutorial http://www.bossable.com/1910/angularjs-nodemailer-contact-form/ to figure out how to use nodemailer.  Is there another way to set up nodemailer so this works?

I would REALLY appreciate some help with this.  It's driving me absolutely crazy ;__;

Comment: I think you need to change `app.get('/',` to `app.get('/*',`

Comment: @YOU Oh my god! Thank for forever.  That worked! I don't know why it worked but it did!

Comment: because in SPA, you serve everything index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you had to serve every request return index.html,

by changing `app.get('/',` to `app.get('/*',`